# 2 errors: (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined)& (npm ERR! missing script: start)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, environment-variables

## ***Problem #1: ENV***

I have 2 JS files: **app.js** (main) & **request.js** ---- (they are all at the same hierarchy. in the root. same as index.html)

**request.js** has the `process.env.APP_KEY` .

I've tried to add `require("dotenv").config();`to both (not at the same time). but I'm getting the same error each time:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

env file:

`API_KEY=5900000000`

react.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const requestCity = async (city) => {
  const baseURL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`;
  const query = `?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`; 
  const response = await fetch(baseURL + query);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

## ***Problem #2: NPM ***

I've installed npm.
but when I tried `npm start`,  I am receiving an error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

or `npm run` or `npm test`:

```
echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1
```

I've looked at other answers in Stackoverflow, and I'm guessing it has something to with **package.json** and it needs **"starts"** or **"test"**. But I don't know what I should type after either one... Or what I need to add, in general.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "weather-js-sy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "2nd weather app. (first with Angela)",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "weather-js-sy"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "node": "^15.3.0"
  }
}
```

I'm open to any suggestions. thank you.

Comment: where are you running the problem #1 file?

Comment: [mcve] please. / looks like that you just copied the project somewhere and try to run it without knowing too much about node and stuff. Does it have a readme about how to run?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem #1

`require` is a **Nodejs** specific function, maybe you are trying to execute this files on the browser?

#### Problem #2

You need to write your task on the script section of package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "here goes the command that yo need to execute when ask for 'start' task "
  },
```

Then for execute these script you need to do `npm run {scriptName}`, npm has some shorthand command for test where you can omit the `run` work `npm test` = `npm run test`